# Manage UITableView with custom UITableViewController created programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, iboutlet

I'm using XCODE 4.2 on iOS5.

I have created a UITableViewController custom, called picker. This is the class content:

```
NSMutableArray *_nameCollection;
NSMutableArray *_imageCollection;
```

With 2 elements each. That works well. If I create programmatically a UITableview, it shows the data correctly.

On the view, I declare the class (inside `(void)viewDidLoad`):

```
self.Picker = [[Picker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
_Picker.delegate = self;
PickerTableViewIB = _Picker.tableView;   // Try to link using a IBOutlet
```

PickerTableViewIB is an Outlet from a Tableview, created inside a subview, using Interface Builder.

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the data source as well? You need that for the table view to get the data for populating. Otherwise the `cellForRow` method will not be called and your cells will not be populated.

```
_Picker.dataSource = self;
```

It would also be a good idea to call `[self.Picker reloadData];` after setting the dataSource.